# How to import data from LibreOffice Calc to a SQL database?

Tags: python, sql, database, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

What's the best way to switch to a database management software from LibreOffice Calc?

I would like to move everything from a master spreadsheet to a database with certain conditions. Is it possible to write a script in Python that would do all of this for me?

The data I have is well structured I have about 300 columns of assets and under every asset there is 0 - ~50 filenames. The asset names are uniform as well as the filenames.

Thank you all!

Comment: Do the rows have any significance? That is, is there a relation between, for example, filename #5 in asset 1 to filename #5 in asset 2?

Comment: No there isn't any relation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a python script that will read this spreadsheet row by row and then run insert statements in a database. In fact, would be even better if you save the spreadsheet as CSV for example, if you only need the data there.

Answer (score 1):

You can ofcourse use python for this task but it might be an overkill.

The CSV export / import sequence is likely much faster, less error prone and needs less ongoing maintainance (e.g if you change the spreadsheet columns). The sequence is roughly as follows:

- select the sheet that you want to import into a DB
- select Files / Save as.. and then text/csv
- select a column separator that will not interfere with your data (e.g. |)

The import sequence into a database depends on your choice of db but today many IDE's and database GUI environments will automatically import / introspect your CSV file and create the table / insert the data for you. Things to be double check:

- You may have to indicate that the first row is a header
- The assigned datatype may need fine tuning if the automated guesses are not optimal